# Create a list of results of all recursive calls performed by a function call

Tags: javascript, list, recursion, fibonacci, function-call

I want to achieve the same result I can get with this code:

```js
function fibs(n) {
  let fibs = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if ((i <= 1)) fibs.push(i)
    else fibs.push(fibs[i - 1] + fibs[i - 2])
  }
  return fibs
}

console.log( fibs(8) )
```

with a recursive function.

Obviously, when you `console.log(fibs(8)` it renders a list like this: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]

My recursive function looks like this:

```js
function fibsRec(n) {
  if (n < 2) return n
  return fibsRec(n - 1) + fibsRec(n - 2)
}

console.log( fibsRec(8) )
```

and if you `console.log(fibsRec(8))` it returns 21, which *is* the 8th Fibonacci number, but doesn't give me the *list* of all the Fibonacci numbers before it. How can I get the list without a loop, just from my recursive function?

**How can I get the same outcome as `fibs()` with `fibsRec()`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**where it goes wrong**

Let's review. If `fibsRec` is meant to return an array, we can first notice that `return n` isn't going to work. `n` is just a number and we need an array.

```js
function fibsRec(n) {
  if (n < 2) return n                    // <- problem one
  return fibsRec(n - 1) + fibsRec(n - 2) // <- problem two
}
```

Second, if `fibsRec` is going to be returning arrays, we cannot simply call `+` for `fibsRec(n - 1)` and `fibsRec(n - 2)`. Watch what happens if we were to try -

```js
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = [4,5,6]
console.log(a + b) // 1,2,34,5,6
```

Maybe you're thinking that's an odd result. Really JavaScript should throw an error for such misuse of `+`, but instead it tries its "best" to perform the addition. To do so, it coerces each array to a string first, then combines the strings together -

```js
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = [4,5,6]
console.log(String(a)) // 1,2,3
console.log(String(b)) // 4,5,6
console.log(a + b) // 1,2,34,5,6
```

**behaviour-oriented design**

To understand how `fibsRec` needs to behave, let's first define some outputs for known inputs -

| f(n) | output |
| --- | --- |
| f(0) | [] |
| f(1) | [0] |
| f(2) | [0,1] |
| f(3) | [0,1,1] |
| f(4) | [0,1,1,2] |
| f(5) | [0,1,1,2,3] |
| f(6) | [0,1,1,2,3,5] |
| ... | ... |

To fix the first problem, easy mode, change `return n` to return a range 0..n instead -

```js
function fibsRec(n) {
  if (n < 2) return range(0,n)           // <- fix one
  return fibsRec(n - 1) + fibsRec(n - 2) // ...
}

const range = (a, b) =>
  a >= b
    ? []
    : [a, ...range(a + 1, b)]
```

**you can't `+` arrays, but you can `fibplus` them...**

To fix the second problem, we need a function that can "add" fibonacci sequences (arrays) because `+` just isn't going to cut it. We'll call our function `fibplus` -

```js
function fibsRec(n) {
  if (n < 2) return range(0,n)
  return fibplus(fibsRec(n - 1), fibsRec(n - 2)) // <- fix two
}
```

We just have to define how `fibplus` will add the sequences to achieve the correct result. Let's work off an example. To compute `fib(6)` we need to "add" `fib(5)` and `fib(4)`. We could just try stacking the two sequences and adding down to get the result -

```
         0 1 1 2 3   == fib(4)
     + 0 1 1 2 3 5   == fib(5)
------------------------------------
       0 1 2 3 5 8   ~~ fib(6)
```

It's very close to `fib(6)` but notice it's off by one. Watch what happens when we prepend a `1` to the smaller number before adding -

```
1 ->   1 0 1 1 2 3
     + 0 1 1 2 3 5
------------------------------------
       1 1 2 3 5 8   ~~ fib(6)
```

Now if we prepend a `0` to the sum ...

```
       1 0 1 1 2 3
     + 0 1 1 2 3 5
------------------------------------
0 -> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8   == fib(6)
```

We now have `fib(6)`! We just need to write `fibplus` to implement this adding technique -

```js
const fibplus = (a, b) =>
  [0, ...zip(add, a, [1, ...b])]
  
const zip = (f, a, b) =>
  a.map((v, i) => f(v, b[i]))
  
const add = (a, b) => a + b
```

**functioning demo**

<kbd>Run</kbd> the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const fib = n =>
  n < 2
    ? range(0, n)
    : fibplus(fib(n - 1), fib(n - 2))
    
const range = (a, b) =>
  a >= b
    ? []
    : [a, ...range(a + 1, b)]
    
const fibplus = (a, b) =>
  [0, ...zip(add, a, [1, ...b])]
  
const zip = (f, a, b) =>
  a.map((v, i) => f(v, b[i]))
  
const add = (a, b) => a + b

console.log(String(fib(20)))
```

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181
```

**visualizing**

So indeed we were able to make `fibsRec` work using `fibplus`, but by mirroring the original recursive process we inherited a lot of inefficiency as well. We can see the sheer amount of duplicated work -

[image: fibplus]

@WillNess comments below and explains another way `fibplus` can be rewritten to save some work, but the real drawback of the approach above is the resulting exponential process. Let's see some other ways to get the result we are looking for.

**other processes**

I like the way you asked the question: *"How can I get the same outcome?"*. Different procedures evolve different processes, and we are not required to create a recursive *branching* process. Instead a *linear iterative* process is more efficient and better suited for the desired output.

Note `fibs` returns an array, but I cast the output as a string for more digestible output -

```js
const fibs = (n, a = 0, b = 1) =>
  n <= 0
    ? []
    : [a, ...fibs(n - 1, b, a + b)]
    
console.log(String(fibs(10)))
```

So how does it work? Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, or other side effects. When a function is referentially transparent, its call can be replaced by its return value, without changing the meaning of our program.

```js
fibs(6)
== fibs(6, 0, 1)
== [0, ...fibs(5, 1, 1)]
== [0, ...[1, ...fibs(4, 1, 2)]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...fibs(3, 2, 3)]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...fibs(2, 3, 5)]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...[3, ...fibs(1, 5, 8)]]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...[3, ...[5, ...fibs(0, 8, 13)]]]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...[3, ...[5, ...[]]]]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...[3, ...[5]]]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, ...[3, 5]]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, ...[2, 3, 5]]]]
== [0, ...[1, ...[1, 2, 3, 5]]]
== [0, ...[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]]
== [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

**wasteful intermediate arrays**

You might notice that the many intermediate arrays is somewhat wasteful and the result could be accomplished with a single array. Let's make a `push` helper to do just that -

```js
const push = (arr, val) =>
  (arr.push(val), arr) 

const fibs = (n, a = 0, b = 1, r = []) =>
  n == 0
    ? r
    : fibs(n - 1, b, a + b, push(r, a))

console.log(String(fibs(10)))
```

Let's see how this one works -

```js
fibs(6)
== fibs(6, 0, 1, [])
== fibs(5, 1, 1, [0])
== fibs(4, 1, 2, [0,1])
== fibs(3, 2, 3, [0,1,1])
== fibs(2, 3, 5, [0,1,1,2])
== fibs(1, 5, 8, [0,1,1,2,3])
== fibs(0, 8, 11, [0,1,1,2,3,5])
== [0,1,1,2,3,5]
```

**streams**

Another fun way to calculate sequences of fibonacci numbers is to use streams. Streams deliver data over time as it is needed, instead of all at once. Because streams allow us to consume only as much as need, we can actually define `fibs` as an *infinite* stream. Notice it is no longer a function -

```js
const fibs =
  stream(0, _ =>
    stream(1, _ =>
      streamAdd(fibs, fibs.next)))
```

The building blocks of our streams are `emptyStream` and `stream`. To construct a non-empty stream, we give provide any value to `stream` and a thunk `_ => ...` where `...` is computation of the next value, if any -

```js
const emptyStream =
  Symbol('emptyStream')

const stream = (value, next) => ({
  value,
  get next() { delete this.next; return this.next = next() }
})
```

Streams as defined here are not the same as JavaScript's built-in generators. The primary difference is they are *persistent*, meaning they can be replayed any number of times. JavaScript's generators have an internal "cursor" and once it advances, you can never rewind it. This is important for our `fibs` stream because you can see it consumes itself twice. If we used generators, advancing the generator for one operation would permanently advance it for all others.

Next we define generic stream operations. `streamAdd` combines two streams of numbers using addition -

```js
const streamAdd = (s1, s2) =>
  s1 === emptyStream || s2 === emptyStream
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s1.value + s2.value, _ => streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next))
```

And because `fibs` is infinite, we need some way to limit how much we bite off. `streamTake` will terminate an infinite stream after that limit is reached -

```js
const streamTake = (s = emptyStream, n = 0) =>
  s === emptyStream || n <= 0
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s.value, _ => streamTake(s.next, n - 1))
```

Finally, to fulfill the desired output, we convert the finite stream to an array -

```js
function streamToArray(s = emptyStream) {
  const r = []
  while (s != emptyStream) {
    r.push(s.value)
    s = s.next
  }
  return r
}
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the stream demo below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const emptyStream =
  Symbol('emptyStream')

const stream = (value, next) => ({
  value,
  get next() { delete this.next; return this.next = next() }
})
  
const streamAdd = (s1, s2) =>
  s1 === emptyStream || s2 === emptyStream
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s1.value + s2.value, _ => streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next))

const streamTake = (s = emptyStream, n = 0) =>
  s === emptyStream || n <= 0
    ? emptyStream
    : stream(s.value, _ => streamTake(s.next, n - 1))

function streamToArray(s = emptyStream) {
  const r = []
  while (s != emptyStream) {
    r.push(s.value)
    s = s.next
  }
  return r
}

const fibs =
  stream(0, _ =>
    stream(1, _ =>
      streamAdd(fibs, fibs.next)))

console.log(String(streamToArray(streamTake(fibs, 20))))
```

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181
```

Comment: nice idea to abstract away the `+`, but your `fibplus` seems a bit too ad-hoc. :) I expected something like  `fibplus(ys, xs) = [...ys, last(ys)+last(xs)]` -- because we create the extended *history* of the *same* process which so far got us `ys`. and because `ys` is the extended history of what got us `xs`, we have `last(xs) = one_before_last(ys)` and thus `fibplus(ys,xs) = [...ys, last(ys)+one_before_last(ys)]`, and then ... we don't need `xs` anymore! now a. under lazy eval it already becomes linear, and b. under strict eval we just explicitly don't calculate what we don't need. :)

Comment: thanks @WillNess, there are many ways we could implement `fibplus` but i chose this way because it didn't pick apart the sub-sequences and thought it illustrated nicely. I agree it is anything but efficient! i also added a lazy implementation at the bottom, because why not :D

Comment: could I ask you a plain JS question?  your `stream` object seems to contain two "fields", the second being `next` which initially is a thunk but then it becomes the calculated value, the next `stream` object in the chain. My question is, when you access it as `.next` in `streamAdd(s1.next, s2.next)`, it can be either that thunk or the calculated stream object. Is that right? So how can it work for both possibilities without the explicit check for what it is?  1/2

Comment: when I run (by changing your last snippet) `typeof fibs.next.next.next.next` _before_ `streamTake(fibs, 10)`,
  how come it prints "object", shouldn't it still be a thunk? 
  and `fibs.next.next.next.next.value` prints as 3, seemingly already calculated? how can that be? is `get` (in `get next() { delete this.next; return this.next = next() }` in the `stream`'s definition) a magic word that makes it execute automatically on (*each? first?*) access?

Comment: hehehe yes, `get` makes `next` a "getter" method so that you can write `s.next` instead of `s.next()`. so the first call to `s.next` will compute the tail, and during the call, the `next` field is replaced with the computed tail. Subsequent calls to `next` will simply return the computed tail.

Comment: thanks. is there some funky namespace business going on there? are there actually several separate entities named `next`? could you show me the disambiguated code snippet?

Comment: I was actually just typing that out, I thought it would be helpful! `const stream = (val, andThen) => ({ value: val, get next() { delete this.next; this.next = andThen() } })`. So `delete this.next` will wipe out the `s.next` getter, and then it sets `s.next` to the computed tail.

Comment: thanks, that does clarify it!

Comment: Another wonderful answer.  I'd love to see this extended with one more possibility, using an `unfold`.  While I could write a separate answer with that, I think it would be better added to this one.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like this (it's also a little bit faster because of caching):

```js
function fibsRec(n) {
  const cache = {
    1: 1,
    0: 1
  }
  
  rec(n)

  return Object.values(cache)

  function rec(n) {
    if (cache[n]) return cache[n]
    cache[n - 1] ??= rec(n - 1)
    cache[n - 2] ??= rec(n - 2)
    return cache[n - 1] + cache[n - 2]
  }
}



console.log(fibsRec(8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course the easy answer would be to make a wrapper function that loops and calls `fibsRec(i)` each time, but that's not what you're looking for.

First, you need to think about what `fibsRec` is doing to see why this isn't naturally as simple as it sounds. As you already know it gets the nth fibonacci number by finding the (n-1)th and (n-2)th and to get those, it keeps going further back.

But that means that to get the n-1 and n-2 numbers, you need to generate the sequence to n-1 and n-2, not only that, but when you start generating that sequence for, let's say n-1, and you have to calculate *it's* previous indices, then you need two more sequences, and so on and so on. It's extremely inefficient.

But the reason I'm bringing this up, is to say that we can't just create an empty array and have it push the number we'd return before returning it, because we're making so many sequences, our array is gonna contain all those results.

Look at this:

```js
function fibArray(n) {
  const output = [];

  function fibsRec(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
      output.push(n)
      return n;
    }

    let num =  fibsRec(n - 2) + fibsRec(n - 1) 
    output.push(num);
    return num;
  }
  fibsRec(n);
  return output
}

console.log( fibArray(8) )
```

See how many times we're calculating a number on the fibonacci sequence?

We definitely can't directly use this approach. But what we **can** use is **dynamic programming**. What we'll do is, memoize (save) each fibonacci number we calculate to a dictionary, and the next time we're looking for it, instead of recursing a new sequence, we'll just get it from the dictionary directly.

That way, we're getting each fibonacci number **only once**. So when we calculate it, we can push it to our output array, and it'll be a clean fibonacci sequence.

```js
function fibArray(n) {
  const output = [];
  const fibs = {}; // Create memo (a dictionary)
  
  function fibsRec(n) {
    if (fibs[n]) return fibs[n]; // Check memo
    if (n < 2) {
      fibs[n] = n;
      output.push(n)
      return n;
    }
    
    let num =  fibsRec(n - 2) + fibsRec(n - 1) // Start with n-2 to eventually call fibsRec(0) before fibsRec(1) and push them in that order
    fibs[n] = num; // Memoize
    output.push(num);
    return num;
  }
  fibsRec(n);
  return output
}

console.log( fibArray(8) )
```

Comment: Voting requires 2 bits. for -1, 0, +1. Answers like yours make me wish that we could use the unused combination for +2. awesome

Comment: Thank you for the really kind words! I'd give your comment +2 if I could :)

Comment: You're welcome. THANK-YOU for the spectacular contribution. Keep em coming!

Comment: You're awesome, your great vibes and support make it all worthwhile :).

Comment: dynamic programming is *not* memoized recursion. the latter works in a top-down manner, the former - bottom-up.

Comment: Check out this [MIT Lecture](https://youtu.be/OQ5jsbhAv_M?t=660) with exactly the example in my answer. Recursion doesn't **have** to be bottom-up.

Comment: recursion is top-down: `fibsRec(n) = ...`, i.e. we start from `n`, and go down to `n-1`, `n-2`, and so on. dynamic programming is bottom-up: it fills up the shared structure from the bottom. the OP first code snippet in the question actually does exactly that.

Comment: @WillNess: Wikipedia [disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) with you, discussing both top-down memoization and bottom-up pre-calculation as forms of dynamic programming.  I'm inclined to agree with Wikipedia, although, of course, it's just a matter of labeling.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks for the link! Will re-check my assumptions. :)

Comment: @ScottSauyet well, looking at the "Overview -- Computer programming" there, it does say "citation needed" i.e. it's just something someone wrote. I'll need more than that to be persuaded. :) WP is full of OR (I should know, I put there plenty of my own.) Or were you referring to some other part of that article?

Comment: @WillNess: That continues through a few examples.  But the only real difference between top-down and bottom-up is the order in which the subproblems are *called*.  In either case, answers to the smaller subproblems are *calculated* and  *cached* before those for the larger ones which depend upon them.  This is the defining characteristic of DP to me.

Comment: @ScottSauyet one difference is that with memoization you are automatically guaranteed to not calculate any non-needed subproblems. Bottom-up is harder to do right, but can be marginally more efficient having avoided any function calls machinery.